# Using the filters in wordpress theme

Tags: profiles

I have a member directory website created with Ultimate Member plugin, where I need  to make the profile image height should be more than the width, but there is no option in Ultimate Member settings, they used only square images, I asked about this in their support forum they gave the answer like bellow.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/i-badly-need-to-make-the-profile-image-hight-more-than-width/

But as I am not able to use this, can any one explain me how to use that.

I need to increase the image height here,  this is the Member Directory page 
https://kayapati.com/demos/alexia/photographers